# How do I specify a callback function after rest parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that receives an some arbitrary number of strings like in this example:

```
function foo(...strings, callback);
```

How do I specify it's types in typescript? I weighed the following alternatives:

1. `functio foo(...strings: string, callback: (err: Error, res: any) => void);`

this is no good because rest parameters have to be last.

2. `foo(...strings: any);`

this is a compromise that will compile but requires forfeiting type checking.

3. `foo(...strings: string|((err: Error, res: any) => void));`

this is a bit more true but is very non-readable and I don't think I saw it in any project.

Is there a best practice to deal with this? What trade offs should be taken into account?

Comment: You can't , only the last parameter can be a rest parameter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: Have you thought returning a promise/async instead? This way you don't have to cope with callback definition, and your code code would look nicer

Comment: Of course I'd rather change the api but is still the conventions in many libraries and I wish to edit a type file for such a library.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you have to change your 'order style', and put your callback before your rest parameters. That would be a better (more readable and more type safe) solution than the other awkward workarounds you listed.